# Why is my addition and subtraction not working?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, readline

So I am using readline-sync to perform basic calculations. Multiplying and dividing work fine, but when I add both numbers it just concatenates them and when I subtract it returns NaN.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");

var enterNum1 = readlineSync.question("Please enter your first number: ");
var enterNum2 = readlineSync.question("Please enter your second number: ");
var operations = ["add", "sub", "mul", "div"];
var selectOperation = readlineSync.keyInSelect(operations, "What operation will you like to perform?");


function addNum(num1, num2){
    console.log("The result is : " + Number(num1) + Number(num2));
}

function subNum(num1, num2){
    console.log("The result is : " + Number(num1) - Number(num2));
}

function mulNum(num1, num2){
    console.log( "The result is : " + Number(num1) * Number(num2));
}

function divNum(num1, num2){
    console.log("The result is : " + Number(num1) / Number(num2));
}

if(selectOperation === 0){
    addNum(enterNum1, enterNum2);
}else if(selectOperation === 1){
    subNum(enterNum1, enterNum2)
}else if(selectOperation === 2){
    mulNum(enterNum1, enterNum2);
}else {
    divNum(enterNum1, enterNum2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your operation in brackets

e.g.

```
console.log("The result is : " + (Number(num1) + Number(num2)));
console.log("The result is : " + (Number(num1) - Number(num2)));
```

**Reasoning**

As per operator precedence, multiplication and division works as they have higher precedence, i.e. they will be executed first. In case of addition and subtraction, the precedence is same and is operated from left to right. Hence, first the the string `"The result is : "` is added to `Number(num1)` and then added to `Number(num2)` which result in concatenation and for subtraction, it becomes trying to subtract a number from a string, resulting in `NaN`

For reference, [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the precedence order of the operators. The JavaScript interpreter tries to concatenate the string and the first number instead of adding both the numbers and then concatenate the result to the string.

To mitigate, you need to direct JavaScript to perform the addition/subtraction before the string concatenation. Parentheses help you do so:

```
console.log("The result is : " + (Number(num1) + Number(num2)));
console.log("The result is : " + (Number(num1) - Number(num2)));
```

Since multiplication and divison have higher precedence to string concatenation, the same behaviour is not observed there.